# rendering `.Rmd` posts as slides in blogdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, hugo, blogdown

I am using `blogdown` to generate a static website from a series of posts stored as `Rmd` files. For some of these, I would like the post to be rendered as ioslides, such as:

```
---
title: "Habits"
author: John Doe
date: March 22, 2005
output: ioslides_presentation
---

# In the morning

## Getting up

- Turn off alarm
- Get out of bed

## Breakfast

- Eat eggs
- Drink coffee
```

`rmardown::render()` creates slides just fine from the file above, but when using it as a post and running `blogdown::serve_site()` the output is rendered as a 'regular' html article (not slides).

Any idea if this can be done, and if so, how?
Best
Thibaut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This use case is documented in the second half of [Section 2.7 of the **blogdown** book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/static-files.html). Basically, you have to

1. Put this Rmd document under `static/`;
2. Add a script `R/build.R`.